# как во flutter продолжать процесс если приложение свернуто на ios?

Tags: flutter, dart

при разработке заметил одну маленькую вещь, использовал `flutter_local_notification` для показа уведомления в определенных операциях и она работает на `android`, а вот на `ios` если сворачиваю приложение (не закрываю), операции останавливаются, а если обратно захожу в приложение то операции продолжаются, как это можно устранить?

Comment: Создавайте issues, узнавайте у автора плагина.

Comment: мне показалось что это связано с xcode, может там какой нибудь запрет стоит по умолчанию?